# Makefile: Reading/splitting an array

Tags: makefile

Say you had the following directory structure:

```
# directory structure
├── GIT-REPO
│   ├── dev
│   ├── production
│   ├── mgmt
```

I'm looking for a way in a Makefile to find the environment based on what directory it is living in.  I found a way to do this in bash with the following:

```
DIR="$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}")" && pwd)"                                                                    
IFS='/' read -r -a DIR_ARRAY <<< "$DIR"                                                                         
GIT_REPO=some-repo                                                                                            

for ((i=0; i < ${#DIR_ARRAY[@]}; i++)) do                                                                            
    if [ "${DIR_ARRAY[$i]}" = "$GIT_REPO" ] ; then                                                                   
        echo ${DIR_ARRAY[$i+1]}                                                                                      
    fi                                                                                                               
done
```

But I'm having a hard time translating this into a Makefile.  Each of these environment directories will have a Makefile as well as subdirectories.  I want to be able to dynamically look up what environment it is under by finding the name of the directory to the right of the $GIT_REPO directory.

Comment: This question is highly unclear (to me). If it depends on an understanding of git, please add the `git` tag.

Answer (score 0):

So here's an example:

```
/home/user/git_repo/mgmt
/home/user/git_repo/prod
/home/user/git_repo/prod/application/
/home/user/git_repo/dev/
/home/user/my_source_files/git_repo/prod/application
```

You'll see there's some similarities, but the overall length of dir's is different.  They all share the `git_repo` and all contain an `environment` (prod, dev, mgmt).  At the top level of each directory above is a `Makefile` where I want to pull the `environment`.  My bash example was a lot more complicated than I needed it to be and could use `sed` instead.  This is what is in my `Makefile` now:

```
GIT_REPO="my_repo"
ENV=$(shell pwd | sed "s/^.*\/$(GIT_REPO)\///" | cut -d / -f 1)
```

What this will do is look for the Git repository text and strip the repository name and any root directory before it.  Then we apply cut and separate it by the '/' path and grab the first element.  This will always return the environment folder.

I have a very specific use case where I want to dynamically get the environment in my Makefile rather than statically defining it each time.